# If $X$ is compact then a subset of $C(X)$ is compact if and only the subset is closed, uniformly bounded and equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding a part of this following proof. The theorem is that is $X$ is a compact metric space and $\mathcal F \subset C(X)$ then $\mathcal F$ is compact if and only if $\mathcal F$ is closed, unifmormly bounded and equicontinuous. I'm having trouble understanding the justification for some of the steps showing that if $\mathcal F$ is compact then it is also equicontinuous.

My book says: suppose that $\mathcal F$ is compact but not equicontinuous at a point $x \in X$. Then there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for each natural number $n$ there is a function in $\mathcal F$ labeled $f_n$ and a point in $X$ labeled $x_n$ for which $|f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|>\epsilon_0$ while $\rho(x_n,x)<\frac{1}{n}$

But I don't see why assuming  that $\mathcal F$ is not equicontinuous can allow us to say this. Can someone please explain this to me? For reference this is Theorem 3 on page 209 of Real Analysis 4th Edition by Royden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A family of functions $\mathscr F$ is called [equicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Definition) at $x$, if

> for all $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ so that $|f(y) - f(x)| <\epsilon $ for all $\rho(x, y)<\delta$ and for all $f\in \mathscr F$.

Now you want to negate this statement, that is,

> There exists $\epsilon_0 >0$, so that for all $\delta >0$, there is $f\in \mathscr F$ and $y\in B_\delta(x)$ so that $|f(y) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon_0$.

Note that this holds for all $\delta >0$ (and of course $f\in \mathscr F$ and $y\in B_\delta(x)$ depends on $\delta$). Thus taking $\delta= 1/n$, there are corresponding $f_n \in \mathscr F$ and $x_n \in B_{1/n}(x)$ so that $|f(x_n ) - f_n(x)| \ge \epsilon_0$, as claimed.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I was reading it was $|f(x_n)-f(x)|> \epsilon_0$ for every $x_n$ in the $\delta_x $ neighborhood around $x $ which couldn't happen since all the $f_n $ are continuous